# PUT request , change headers and save response in core data using RESTkit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, put

I want to send a request to a server, a PUT request with the following request headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

And the following `NSDictionary`:

```
{"title": "Sumit"}
```

I am making a put request using reskit, put request is made but gives error related to headers.
I want to know how to set headers and dict when sending a request to a remote server.
Also, which method is best of `RKObjectManager` for this task among :-

method 1:-

```
- NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager requestWithObject:newImage
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodPUT
                                                     path:[kImageUrl stringByAppendingString:imageUrl]
                                               parameters:jsonParameters];
```

method 2:-

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)multipartFormRequestWithObject:(id)object
                                                 method:(RKRequestMethod)method
                                                   path:(NSString *)path
                                             parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                              constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block;
```

ERROR THAT I AM GETTING :-

```
(400 Bad Request) [0.4221 s]: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 
"Expected content type {(
   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "application/json"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0xa0951c0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Bad Request,
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest  
http://staging.zoomdeck.com/api/image/c5ot31sxnh8v/>, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://staging.zoomdeck.com/api/image/c5ot31sxnh8v/,  
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<
NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa194530>}
2013-01-16 17:19:43.860 Zoomdeck[2905:4a07] E 
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:285 Object request failed: 
Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error 
Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0xa0951c0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Bad Request,  
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest 
http://staging.zoomdeck.com/api/image/c5ot31sxnh8v/>, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://staging.zoomdeck.com/api/image/c5ot31sxnh8v/, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa194530>}
2013-01-16 17:19:43.861 Zoomdeck[2905:c07] Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rest service expects content type

```
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

or

```
"application/json"
```

but it gets content type

```
text/plain
```

You have to set the contentType for your request like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager requestWithObject:newImage
                                               method:RKRequestMethodPUT
                                                 path:[kImageUrl stringByAppendingString:imageUrl]
                                           parameters:jsonParameters];



[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried a lot of methods like this... but internally in restkit handling is done is some way due to which i hve found out that , we can set it before making NSMutableRequest object like this.   manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;  It works now by this...